# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement in c# oledb?

Tags: c#

I am having a table called SubMaster_Accounts, which contains 9 fields. In which I want to insert data to some fields and i want to store some other fields as NULL. I tried to write the query using query string, The sql query works perfectly when i insert the data for all the fields, but when i insert data as NULL to some of the fields it shows syntax error in Insert command. The fields which i want to insert as NULL are not constraints.

How can i do it?

This is my query string.

```
insert into SubMaster_Account ([SMcode], [MSname], [Sname], [Openbalrs],
 [Openbalrs1], [Openbalmet], [Openbalmet1], [Creditdays], [Sdesc])
 values ('" + SMcode + "','" + MSname + "','" + Sname + "'," + 
Openbalrs + ",'" + Openbalrs1 + "'," + Openbalmet + ",'" + 
Openbalmet1 + "'," + Creditdays + ",'" + Sdesc + "')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your query to use parameters instead of inline literals.

With your current approach, you *migth* be prone to SQL injection attacks, if any of those values from the user.

You *are* prone to SQL syntax errors, as you've experienced, if you try to use any values with single quotes in them, or whatnot.

These problems go away with parameters.

Comment: who keeps on teaching those stuff!? noobs should be taught how to use parametrized queries from day 1.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an artifact of the fact that SQL is usually taught without a programming language around it, and when you get to the programming language, writing the SQL has to be done in a string, and thus when you come around to adding things that change to the string, it is just natural to fall back to string concatenation.